# Passing a list as positional arguments to a function like Python in F#

Tags: f#, iterable, function-parameter

In Python, you can write this:

```py
def add(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

list_of_args = [4, 5, 6]
print(add(*list_of_args))
```

The asterisk in front of `list_of_args` expands the iterable so that its elements are the values of the parameters a, b and c.

Can you do something similar in F#? Specifically, I'm looking for a good or idiomatic F# solution and do not want to muck around with reflection and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920094/how-can-i-convert-between-f-list-and-f-tuple

Comment: I understand what you're asking but what's the use case for code of this sort?  I mean I can see passing a list as a parameter and I can see functions with variadic argument lists but I'm not quite following where you'd want to use code like this.

Comment: I'm gluing together together two api:s that deal with 3d vectors differently. One likes to represent them as a three item list and the other has three parameters x, y and z on all functions that uses vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# does not have anything like this out of the box - mainly because F# is statically typed language and so supporting similar patters is difficult (list may only contain values of one type, while function may have different parameters).

As mentioned in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920094/how-can-i-convert-between-f-list-and-f-tuple), you can emulate similar idea using reflection, which is going to be slow and unsafe, but if you have really good reason for doing this, you might give it a try.

Using the `tupleToList` function from the previous answer and a few active patterns, you can write:

```
// Converts any F# tuple to a list of objects using reflection
let tupleToList t = 
    if Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) 
        then Some (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields t |> Array.toList)
        else None

// Active pattern that accepts any object and extracts its members
// if it is a tuple or a sequence of values (e.g. list)
let (|Arguments|_|) (a:obj) = 
  match a, tupleToList a with
  | _, Some t -> Some t
  | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as l, _ -> 
      l |> Seq.cast |> List.ofSeq |> Some
  | _ -> None

// Treat the argument as an int (this may fail)
let (|Int|_|) (a:obj) = match a with :? int as n -> Some n | _ -> None

// Function that assumes to get three integers
let f (Arguments [Int a;Int b;Int c]) = 
  printfn "%d" (a + b + c)

f (1, 2, 3) // Call with tuple
f [1;2;3]   // Call with a list
f (1, "hi", 3, 141.1)  // This will fail at runtime, but compiler allows it :-(
```

This is probably not very idiomatic F# and I would try to avoid it, but it might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the anser is "can't be done" without reflection?

Comment: I think the answer by @Daniel is a good alternative (wtihout reflection) if you're happy to use static methods instead of plain functions.

Comment: "*mainly because F# is statically typed language and so supporting similar patters is difficult*" C++ is a statically typed language but can handle this effortlessly. ;-]

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
type T =
  static member func([<ParamArray>] args: 'T[]) = printfn "%A" args

T.func(1, 2, 3)

let args = [|1; 2; 3|]
T.func(args)
```

Both calls print `[|1; 2; 3|]`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know your intention here. If you just need a way to treat the arguments of a specific function as a first-class value, you can simply define the function to take a tuple of values as its single argument:

```
let f (a, b, c) = a + b + c
let args = (1, 2, 3)
let result = f args
```

For methods, this is actually the "default style".
The only drawback: You cannot really use partial application with such functions/methods.