# The type 'obj list option' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I used the following code to [convert a tuple to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920094/how-can-i-convert-between-f-list-and-f-tuple) and then I tried to find the average of list. But I faced with that error.

```
 The type 'obj list option' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>, IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method
```

Here is the code:

```
let Average (touple)  =

 let tupleToList t = 
    if Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) 
        then Some (Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields t |> Array.toList)
        else None
 let k=tupleToList touple
 let mutable sum=0
 for i in k do 
   sum<-sum+k.[i]


let touple4= 6,18,6,9
Average touple4
```

Comment: Tuples can contain different types together

Answer (score 3):

`tupleToList` returns an [option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx)al list ; that is if the given argument is a tuple it gives back `Some` list otherwise `None`.
An option type cannot be enumerated (use a for loop on it) so you need to verify that you get `Some` and extract the list inside it (or do something else if you got `None`)

One way to do that is with [pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx)

```
match tupleToList touple with
| Some k -> // use k to do what you want
| None   -> // do something else
```

Beware that all path in an expression must return the same type ; all the branch in a match must returns the same kind of thing (ex: return 0 in the None case or return Some sum if you got Some list and None for None)

You could also use some function inside the [Option module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370544.aspx)

*As a side note, you should look inside the [List module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx) for example to simply the summation of it's values.*

Answer (score 1):

Your tupleToList function returns an Option. To enumerate the result, you would have to use pattern matching or modify the function to return a list. In this case it's very easy - if the parameter is not a tuple, return an empty list.

A tuple can contain different types, so the returned list will be an obj list. You will need to convert it (or unbox and cast) to a type that supports (+) and DivideByInt operators to calculate the average. Converting is a better solution because it will work with tuples of different types (eg. int*float)

You should also try to use more functional and less imperative programming style.

```
let Average (tuple)  =
    let tupleToList t = 
    if Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(t.GetType()) 
        then Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields t |> Array.toList
        else []
    tuple
    |> tupleToList
    |> List.map System.Convert.ToDouble
    |> List.average

let tuple4= 6,18,6,9
Average tuple4
```