# F# build a list/array of values + consecutive duplicates

Tags: f#

I need to pack data like this:

```
let data = [1; 2; 2; 3; 2; 2; 2; 4]
let packed = [(1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 1); (2, 3); (4, 1)]
```

Where each item say how much times it exist before the next. However, it must work with non-adjacent duplications.

I can work this with classical imperative code, but wonder how do this functionally.

Also, `Seq.countBy` not work because it take in account all the values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have an imperative version, you can [follow a set of small steps to refector to a recursive implementation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/12/01/recurse).

## Recursion

While I don't know what your imperative version looks like, here's a recursive version:

```
let pack xs =
    let rec imp acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | h::t ->
        match acc with
        | [] -> imp [(h, 1)] t
        | (i, count) :: ta ->
            if h = i
            then imp ((i, count + 1) :: ta) t
            else imp ((h, 1) :: (i, count) :: ta) t
    xs |> imp [] |> List.rev
```

This function has the type `'a list -> ('a * int) list when 'a : equality`. It uses a private 'implementation function' called `imp` to do the work. This function is recursive, and threads an accumulator (called `acc`) throughout. This accumulator is the result list, having the type `('a * int) list`.

If the accumulator list is empty, the head of the original list (`h`), as well as the count `1`, is created as a tuple as the only element of the updated accumulator, and the `imp` function is recursively called with that updated accumulator.

If the accumulator already contains at least one element, the element is extracted via pattern matching, and the element in that tuple (`i`) is compared to `h`. If `h = i`, the accumulator is updated; otherwise, a new tuple is consed on `acc`. In both cases, though, `imp` is recursively called with the new accumulator.

You can call it with a *list* equivalent to your original tuple like this:

```
> pack [1; 2; 2; 3; 2; 2; 2; 4];;
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 1); (2, 3); (4, 1)]
```

## Fold

Once you have a recursive version, you often have the recipe for a version using a fold. In this case, since the above `pack` function has to reverse the accumulator in the end (using `List.rev`), a *right fold* is most appropriate. In F#, this is done with the built-in `List.foldBack` function:

```
let pack' xs =
    let imp x = function
        | (i, count) :: ta when i = x -> (i, count + 1) :: ta
        | ta -> (x, 1) :: ta
    List.foldBack imp xs []
```

In this case, the function passed to `List.foldBack` is a bit too complex to pass as an anonymous function, so I chose to define it as a private inner function. It's equivalent to the recursive `imp` function used by the above `pack` function, but you'll notive that it doesn't have to call itself recursively. Instead, it just has to return the new value for the accumulator.

The result is the same:

```
> pack' [1; 2; 2; 3; 2; 2; 2; 4];;
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 1); (2, 3); (4, 1)]
```

Comment: Nice answer.  A few things small changes can make it even clearer, in my opinion.  You can replace `let imp x acc = match acc ...` with `let imp x = function ...` to avoid naming an identifier that you just immediately destructure.  More importantly, you can switch the order of the pattern match cases and use a `when` clause to unify the `[]` and `x <> i` cases:  `| (i, count) :: ta when i = x -> (i, count+1) :: ta | ta -> (x, 1) :: ta`.

Comment: @kvb Those are very nice simplifications! Thank you. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

My solution assumes the `data` collection is a list. If having it as a tuple (as per your example) was intentional then for my solution to work the tuple has to be converted to a list (an example how to do it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2920928/3330348)).

```
let groupFunc list = 
    let rec groupFuncRec acc lst init count =
        match lst with
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | head::[] when head = init
            -> groupFuncRec ((init, count)::acc) [] 0 0
        | head::[] when head <> init
            -> groupFuncRec ((head, 1)::acc) [] 0 0
        | head::tail when head = init 
            -> groupFuncRec acc tail head (count+1)
        | head::tail when head <> init
            -> groupFuncRec ((init, count)::acc) tail head 1
    let t = List.tail list
    let h = List.head list
    groupFuncRec [] t h 1
```

When I run the function on your sample data I get back the expected result:

```
 list = [(1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 1); (4, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `Seq.countBy` to work by including some positional information in its argument. Of course, you need then to map back to your original data.

```
[1; 2; 2; 3; 2; 2; 2; 4]
|> Seq.scan (fun (s, i) x ->
    match s with
    | Some p when p = x -> Some x, i
    | _ -> Some x, i + 1 ) (None, 0)
|> Seq.countBy id
|> Seq.choose (function 
| (Some t, _), n -> Some(t, n)
| _ -> None )
|> Seq.toList
// val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 1); (2, 3); (4, 1)]
```