# Convert list to instance of my type

Tags: f#

I have the types which declared like this:

```
[<DataContract>] 
type Defect = 
    {
        [<field: DataMember(Name="referenceId")>]
        Referenceid  : string
        [<field: DataMember(Name="comment")>]
        Comment : string
        [<field: DataMember(Name="start")>]
        Start : DateTime
        [<field: DataMember(Name="finish")>]
        Finish : DateTime
    }
```

This type have 4 fields. And I have the list with 4 elements.
I have other types with `n` fields.  And I have lists with `n` elements.

Is there universal way to create instances of my types from the lists such way, so each element of the list will be corresponding field of the type ?

Comment: create a json string from your list and then json-serialize that string to your object (using JSON.net)?

Comment: in this case i need to write List2JSON function for each kind of my type? in the other words - do I need to have as many list2json functions as many types I have?

Comment: You need only one List2Json function that would have type `list -> string` where the output is your json string, then using a package called `Newtonsoft.JSON` you could have a function to deserialize that string like this: `let deserialize (jsonInput: string) : 'a = JsonConvert.Deserialize<'a>(jsonInput)`

Answer (score 5):

You can create instances of record types using reflection. Consider the code below:

```
let make<'record> (values: obj []) = 
    let typ = typeof<'record>
    let fieldInfos = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typ)

    let orderedValues = 
        // here you might need to reorder values using fieldInfos
        ...

    FSharpValue.MakeRecord(typ, values) :?> 'record
```

The only thing that might be tricky is getting the values in the right order so that they end up in the right fields.

I believe the order you want is the order of declaration, but if the values in your list are labeled with field names, you might want to implement that ordering logic anyway just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you drop down to Reflection-based programming, or type everything as `obj`, I'm pretty sure there isn't any automatic way to do such a thing.

Consider the `Defect` type in the OP. Structurally, it has two `string` elements, and two `DateTime` elements. This is closely related to the **tuple** type:

```
string * string * DateTime * DateTime
```

The differences between record types and tuples are:

- Records have *named* elements; tuple elements are unnamed.
- Record elements can be referenced out of order; tuple elements are ordered.

In other words, this expression still compiles as a `Defect` value, even though the order of elements are different from the order of declaration in the original type:

```
let d = {
    Finish = DateTime.Now
    Comment = "foo"
    Start = (DateTime 42L)
    Referenceid = "bar" }
```

You can still write out a record value in the order in which the named elements were defined:

```
let d' = {
    Referenceid = "bar"    
    Comment = "foo"
    Start = (DateTime 42L)
    Finish = DateTime.Now }
```

*Structurally*, this value is equivalent to this tuple:

```
let t = ("bar", "foo", DateTime 42L, DateTime.Now)
```

By now, it should be clear that the OP question is equivalent to the *frequently asked question*: [How can I convert between list and tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2920094/126014)

The short answer is: **you can't**.

These types are *structurally* different.

Given the `Defect` type, what would the type of the equivalent list?

It can't be `string list`, because that can't possible contain `DateTime` values. It can't be `DateTime list`, because that can't possible contain `string` values.

The type issue *can* be solved by defining a Discriminated Union:

```
type DefectElement = Text of string | Time of DateTime

let l = [Text "bar"; Text "foo"; Time (DateTime 42L); Time DateTime.Now]
```

Now `l` has the type `DefectElement list`. This doesn't solve the problem, though, because it's **not guaranteed to contain exactly four elements**, in that order.

Here are some other valid values of the type `DefectElement list`:

```
[Text "bar"; Time (DateTime 42L); Text "foo"; Time DateTime.Now]
[Text "bar"; Time (DateTime 42L); Text "foo"; Time DateTime.Now; Text "baz"]
[Text "bar"; Time (DateTime 42L); Text "foo"]
[Text "bar"; Text "foo"; Text "foo"; Text "bar"]
List.empty<DefectElement>
```

You will notice that *none* of these can be meaningfully, or unambiguously, interpreted as values corresponding to `Defect`.