# F# flatten nested tuples

Tags: f#, tuples, flatten

is there a way to flatten tuples of arbitrary size in F# without explicitly mapping them?

```
(fun ((((a0,a1),a2),b),c) ->  (a0,a1,a2,b,c))
```

As a note I'm getting these kind of tuples from FParsec but the capability would be convenient if it was available generally.

thanks,

Comment: In FParsec, you can use the `tuple3, tuple4, tuple5` or `pipe3, pipe4, pipe5` functions to combine more parsers, that might obviate your need for something like that.

Comment: @TheInnerLight great point thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it easily, but with a bit of reflection it is possible:

```
let isTuple tuple =
    Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple(tuple.GetType()) 

let tupleValues (tuple : obj) = 
    Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields tuple |> Array.toList

let rec flatten tupleFields =
    tupleFields |> List.collect(fun value ->
        match isTuple value with
        | true -> flatten (tupleValues value)
        | false -> [value]
    )

let tupleToList (tuple : obj) = 
    if isTuple tuple
        then Some (tupleValues tuple |> flatten)
        else None
```

So, for example:

```
let s = tupleToList ((100,101,102,103),1,2,3,(4,5))
```

Will give you:

```
[100; 101; 102; 103; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

NOTE: This answer is based on code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920094/how-can-i-convert-between-f-list-and-f-tuple).

Comment: Reflection should be an absolute last resort though; it's generally terrible in terms of type safety and performance. I would much rather do what @TheInnerLight said and use FParsec's dedicated functions.

Comment: @Tarmil Wholly agree with you Tarmill - just given the way I phrased the question Sean's answer's correct.