# how to flatten nested tuples in c#?

Tags: c#, tuples

I have nested tuples like - `Tuple<Tuple<Tuple<string,string>, string>, string>`.
I want to flatten them like `Tuple<string,string,string,string>`. I see that is can be done in f#. Is there a version of - [F# flatten nested tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919568/f-flatten-nested-tuples) - in c#

Comment: I think rather than flattening them, you should consider redesigning this. Horrific, with all due respect.

Comment: `var flattened = new Tuple<string, string, string, string>(t.Item1.Item1.Item1, t.Item1.Item1.Item2, t.Item1.Item2, t.Item2);`

Comment: Note that the F# code in your link does not do what you claim. It flattens nested tuples into a list. Is that what you want or do you want it turned into another tuple?

Comment: @JuanR while I totally agree with you, this what I have to live with a legacy library :(

Comment: @Milan: Sorry to hear that. Well, you are in luck sir for I have provided an answer to your problems below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your `Tuple` to the flat list with recursion and Deep-First Search. Try this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> DFS(object t)
{
    var type = t.GetType();
    if (type.FullName?.StartsWith("System.Tuple") != true) // or check inheritanse from ITuple
        yield return t;

    var items = type.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Item"))
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(t))
        .ToArray();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        foreach (var innerItem in DFS(item))
        {
            yield return innerItem;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var input = Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create(Tuple.Create("a0", "a1"), "a2"), "b", "c");
var items = DFS(input).ToArray();
// items[2] would be "a2"
```

Please note that reflection may slow down your app so try to avoid it while it is possible

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you insist in using this rather obnoxious design, here is how you could do it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructs a tuple our of an array of arguments
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of argument.</typeparam>
/// <param name="values">The values.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static object ConstructTuple<T>(params T[] values)
{
    Type genericType = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + values.Length);
    Type[] typeArgs = values.Select(_ => typeof(T)).ToArray();
    Type specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
    object[] constructorArguments = values.Cast<object>().ToArray();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(specificType, constructorArguments);
}

/// <summary>
/// Flattens a tupple into an enumeration using reflection.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of objects the nested tuple contains.</typeparam>
/// <param name="tuple">The tuple to flatten.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<T> FlattenTupple<T>(object tuple)
{            
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
    var type = tuple.GetType();

    if (type.GetInterface("ITuple") == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("This is not a tuple!");

    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(tuple);
        if (property.PropertyType.GetInterface("ITuple") != null)
        {                    
            var subItems = FlattenTupple<T>(value);
            items.AddRange(subItems);
        }
        else
        {
            items.Add((T)value);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Tuple<Tuple<Tuple<string, string>, string>, string> tuple =
            new Tuple<Tuple<Tuple<string, string>, string>, string>(new Tuple<Tuple<string, string>, string>(new Tuple<string, string>("value1", "value2"), "value2b"), "value2c");

var items = FlattenTupple<string>(tuple);
var flattened = ConstructTuple(items.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(flattened);
```

Output:

> (value1, value2, value2b, value2c)

Sample 2 (integers):

```
Tuple<Tuple<Tuple<int, int>, int>, int> intTuple =
            new Tuple<Tuple<Tuple<int, int>, int>, int>(new Tuple<Tuple<int, int>, int>(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2), 3), 4);

var intItems = FlattenTupple<int>(intTuple);
var flattened2 = ConstructTuple(intItems.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(flattened2);
```

Output:

> (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: 2 important notes on this. Make sure you use the same type and make sure you have no more than 6 elements.

Comment: Thank you @Franck. Yes, the assumption is the type of values is the same. Otherwise you can use `object` as the type. I believe the limitation for elements is 8. Then again, if you nest another tuple for element number 8, you essentially get unlimited tuple size since we are unpacking them anyways.

Comment: @JuanR This is great answer. I find Aleks great as well. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer this!

Answer (score -1):

If you have a single item then create a converter which is easier to manage especially if you have a `List` eventually.

```
public Tuple<string, string, string, string> ConvertSomething(Tuple<Tuple<Tuple<string,string>, string>, string> original)
{
    return new Tuple<string, string, string, string>
               (
                   original.Item1.Item1.Item1, 
                   original.Item1.Item1.Item2,
                   original.Item1.Item2,
                   original.Item2
               );
}
```

Please note that `Tuple` is not meant to be modify along the way. If you do need it, it mean you actually have a very bad design. Best solution remain to rethink how things work.

Comment: I think he wants a dynamic way, not a static one.