# FSharp check if tuple type or not

Tags: f#

I am wanting to format a tuple in a specific way and I am trying to do that by checking the type of the tuple (2 element, 3 element etc.). I am getting an error on the third line saying:

```
This runtime coercion of type test from type
'd
to
  'a * ('b * 'c)
involves an indeterminate type based on the information prior to this program point. 
Runtime type tests are not allowed on some type. Further type annotations are needed.
```

Here is my attempt:

```ml
  let namer x =
    match x with
    | :? ('a * ('b * 'c)) as a, b, c -> sprintf "%s_%s_%s" (a.ToString()) (b.ToString()) (c.ToString())
    | :? ('a * 'b) as a, b -> sprintf "%s_%s" (a.ToString()) (b.ToString())
    | a -> sprintf "%s" (a.ToString())
```

How should you do something like this? I want to be able to format the string based on the type of tuple.

What I am ultimately wanting is to be able to "flatten" a nested tuple to a string without a bunch of parenthesis. For example:

```ml
// What I want
let x = (1, (2, (3, 4)))
let name = namer x
printfn "%s" name
> 1_2_3_4
```

**Update**: This is different than the question "How can i convert between F# List and F# Tuple?" found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920094/how-can-i-convert-between-f-list-and-f-tuple). I know how to do that. What I am wanting is to be able to detect if I have a tuple and what type of tuple. The ideal is a generic function that could take a single element, a tuple, or nested 2 element tuples. For example, legal arguments would be:

```ml
let name = namer 1
// or
let name = namer (1, 2)
// or 
let name = namer (1, (2, 3))
// or
let name = namer (1, (2, (3, 4)))
```

I also want to handle non-integer values. For example:

```ml
let name = namer (1, ("2", (3, "chicken")))
```

Comment: Why are you modelling as nested tuples?   It’s not really that common in F#

Comment: @7sharp9 agreed that it is not common. In this case I have a Computation Expression where I have nested for...in...do loops where I want to keep track of the iterator value and use that for an id when I call `Run` at the end. I'll have a blogpost where I detail it out later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with a bit of reflection and a co-recursive function:

```ml
let isTuple tuple =
    tuple.GetType() |> Reflection.FSharpType.IsTuple 

let getFields (tuple: obj) = 
    tuple |> Reflection.FSharpValue.GetTupleFields |> Array.toList

let rec flatten fields =
    List.collect namer fields

and namer (tuple: obj) = 
    if isTuple tuple
    then tuple |> getFields |> flatten
    else [tuple]

namer(1, "test") |> printfn "%A"
namer(1, ("2", (3, "chicken"))) |> printfn "%A"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPawMhEMXvfopBCOxCKyS9BVLIJSHQUxN6KTlYM3ZtjS46OQTy3bf@WbqUxsOgzs/3nqPjo/IBh8EigYmHS28RqNQVg7TKXmyRDtcemxZuz/CK2qIi453Y7DsZ@twSu/ExY1nqE2lj0J4iNEVhCf7jq4UVTKJ3pd6kvVS7jIwSCVyHIK@C/IuJVB0CKtBWEqEDXbmaOCNCeZuFwckzhrHPmHSnenMvlNF/B1CTdkn@N@70q3QYzQuGNiK8F@7IWLWYPwAnjMTL0PpgHGkHfLbmE9DwBU/1KaGqM@obHW/b//ww/AA)

Inspired by:

- [How can i convert between F# List and F# Tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920094/how-can-i-convert-between-f-list-and-f-tuple)
- [F# flatten nested tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919568/f-flatten-nested-tuples)
- [How to have two methods calling each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680606/how-to-have-two-methods-calling-each-other)

Comment: Does this handle the case of a singleton value? For example if it was just the value of : 1 or "test"

Comment: This is excellent! I was able to add the check to `namer` to handle the case of a singleton value. Thank you! This was hugely helpful.